# How do I read through a HTTP response and select a particular part of it?

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to web scrape by requesting the url, using beautiful soup to search for all `i` and `a` tags.

I am struggling to figure out how to make sure the script ensures that both tags are present before writing this to a txt file and then reading it once more to extract the url.

I am ultimately creating a pdf downloader that will crawl the website, find the links, open them up and download the pdf files on the final page.

When I try the `if FILETYPE in file_link`:

I get this error:

```
if FILETYPE in file_link:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

How can I rectify this?

Here is my code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import constants as c

URL = c.url
DOMAIN = c.domain
FILETYPE = '.html'


def get_soup(url):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')


for link in get_soup(URL).find_all('a'):
    file_link = link.get('href')
    if FILETYPE in file_link:
        print(f"{DOMAIN}{file_link}")
```

Comment: What is the actual url so I can test it myself?

Comment: Yes, I've noticed the same. It is a bit weird why the links are available but permissions aren't given. Questions that arise are, what is there to be hidden?

Comment: I tried that method and was successful the first time but every following attempt received the 403.

What I have done instead is scrape the pages extracted from this original code to find all 'a' tags, specifically ones with the class headerpdf as this is the only labelled class on each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experimenting on my own and it seemed to work. I think your issue is that an  tag in the page you are trying to scrape doesn't have an href attribute.

I changed your code a little bit to handle that case

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

URL = "https://www.vatican.va/offices/papal_docs_list.html"
FILETYPE = '.html'


def get_soup(url):
    return bs(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')


for link in get_soup(URL).find_all('a'):
    if (file_link := link.get("href")) is not None:
        if FILETYPE in file_link:
            print(f"{file_link}")
```

In the for loop I assign the file_link variable using the [walrus](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) operator to directly check if it is not None and only execute the check for the `".html"` if it has an actual value.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for responding so rapidly. It's greatly appreciated.

I have tried the same code here, but I now receive a new error code.

The first if statement works fine and that has removed all responses with None following the url. When I add the second if statement we get an issue.

The following is the error that is popping up:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple

Comment: @C4r as said. This code worked with the website I tested. I need the url you are using to debug further

Comment: this is the url: vatican.va/offices/papal_docs_list.html

Comment: It worked for me. My guess would be make sure to use the full url like it edited it into my answer. If it still doesn't work please provide the version of BeautifulSoup and requests you are using

Comment: Thank you, I've been able to get it to work. I had two entries in the filetype var and it was causing issues.

Comment: Glad to hear it